# В чем профит от использования Topshelf при построении сервисов перед традиционным подходом?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-service

Есть либа Topshelf с помощью которой можно создавать сервисы и которую многие рекомендуют.

Собственно в чем профит от использования Topshelf при построении сервисов перед традиционным подходом?

Comment: Полагаю что по вашему вопросу все уже написано тут  https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview/faq.html#why-would-i-want-to-use-topshelf Если кратко - нет времени разбираться как устроены сервисы изнутри, берете TopShelf и работаете только над логикой сервиса. А какой еще может быть профит от использования любого другого фреймворка - экономия времени.

Comment: @rdorn ответом бы оформили.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Полагаю что по вашему вопросу все уже написали авторы TopShelf  [тут](https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview/faq.html#why-would-i-want-to-use-topshelf)

Если кратко - нет времени разбираться как устроены сервисы изнутри, берете TopShelf и работаете только над логикой сервиса. А какой еще может быть профит от использования любого другого фреймворка - экономия времени.